# Is it possible to have multiple keys point to the same object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Basically I want to call `myList[i]` and get the same value for i = 1, 2, 3, 4 then a second value for 5, 6, 7, 8 and so on. I don't really want to copy-paste the value for 1 into 2, 3, 4.

Comment: What exactly is the issue with this?

Comment: Yes, that's how references work in JavaScript. It's significantly more work to *not* do that. What is the problem? What have you tried and what's going wrong?

Comment: You can create a custom function that adds the same value to multiple "i" in the same object. But this value must be a non-primite in order to point to the same exact value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this -

```
myList[Math.floor((i-1)/4)]

where i = 1, 2, 3, 4 ...
```

But if `i` starts from `0`, then

```
myList[Math.floor(i/4)]
```

Adjust the +/- 1 according to your requirements.

Where `4` is the block size to which you need to divide the array with.

Comment: thank you, but I need it to work with irregular intervals. I might just have to use a function and lots of ifs instead...

Comment: Is there logic for generating those irregular intervals? Can you tell me how are these intervals generated? I can may be help with a solution outside the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of objects

```js
const arr = [...Array(4).fill({ value: 1 }), ...Array(4).fill({ value: 3 })];

console.log(arr[0].value);
console.log(arr[2].value);
console.log(arr[4].value);
console.log(arr[6].value);
arr[0].value = 2;
console.log(arr[0].value);
console.log(arr[2].value);
console.log(arr[4].value);
console.log(arr[6].value);
```

Each element is a reference to the same object.

That's not possible with an array of primitives.

Comment: Re: the console output in your snippet: I presume the way Stack Overflow uses object IDs in comments is to avoid circular references. Can someone link to a reference for this kind of implementation?